# SqlServer.Management.Smo on SQL Server 2008 R2 why does transfer of non table objects delete table data

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, smo

I have a C# 4.7.1 program where I used SMO (32 bit) to copy stored procedures and views from one database (1) to a second database (2).  The SQL Server is 2008 R2 SP3 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

**Background**:  Database 1 is a copy my test database with environment specific values set correctly inside the stored procedures and views.  Database 2 is a restored database to my Test system from Production.  The goal was to retain the Test specific values in the stored procedures and views as well as any pre-production stored procedures and views.

The program works to retain my stored procedures and views that are Test specific but has an unwanted side-effect of deleting table data.  I'm hoping someone familiar with the SMO can see what I'm doing or not doing that is causing the data in my tables to be removed.

Thank you very much for any help.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using System;

class Program
{       
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Server SourceServer = new Server(@"SQLSRVR\Instance2");
        Server DestinationServer2 = new Server(@"SQLSRVR\Instance1");

        try 
        {
                //Using SQL Server authentication 
                SourceServer.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;
                SourceServer.ConnectionContext.Login = "UserID";
                SourceServer.ConnectionContext.Password = "Password";
                SourceServer.ConnectionContext.Connect();
                DestinationServer1.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;
                DestinationServer1.ConnectionContext.Login = "UserID";
                DestinationServer1.ConnectionContext.Password = "Password";
                DestinationServer1.ConnectionContext.Connect();

                Database dbSource1 = SourceServer.Databases["dbData"];
                Database dbDestination1 = DestinationServer1.Databases["dbData"];

                Transfer trsfrDB1 = new Transfer(dbSource1);
                trsfrDB1.CopyAllObjects = false;
                trsfrDB1.CopyAllSchemas = false;
                trsfrDB1.CopyAllUserDefinedDataTypes = true;
                trsfrDB1.CopyAllTables = false;
                trsfrDB1.CopyData = false;
                trsfrDB1.CopyAllStoredProcedures = true;
                trsfrDB1.CopyAllViews = true;
                trsfrDB1.DropDestinationObjectsFirst = true;
                trsfrDB1.DestinationServer = DestinationServer1.Name;
                trsfrDB1.DestinationDatabase = dbDestination1.Name;
                Console.WriteLine("dbData start");
                trsfrDB1.TransferData();
                Console.WriteLine("dbData end");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (SourceServer.ConnectionContext.IsOpen)
            {
                SourceServer.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
            }
            if (DestinationServer1.ConnectionContext.IsOpen)
            {
                DestinationServer1.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: References used in the program include: Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo; Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo; Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended; Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum

Comment: I'm running a test now to determine if the DropDestinationObjectsFirst property is my issue.  Per MS if it is set to true it drops the objects before the transfer is run.  I was assuming it only dropped the objects being copied so testing now with it set to false to see what happens.

Comment: ok, if I set the DropDestinationObjectsFirst value to false then when the transfer begins it can not copy over the objects because they already exist.  So keeping that property at true for now.

Comment: For now I'm going to run with a stored procedure to recreate static objects each time I refresh my test system.  I'd really like something more dynamic that can collect all my test objects (of stored proc & view type) prior to the refresh and then put those back after the refresh.  If anyone decides to take a stab at this I'm keeping my project and willing to run some tests to work through it.  I'm out of ideas at the moment though.